# c++ time.h, clock_gettime(), semantic error, how to link real-time library in Eclipse?

Tags: c++

I have some problem using the clock_gettime() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

timespec timer_start;
timespec timer_end;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timer_start);
// sleep for 5 seconds
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5000));
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timer_end);

std::cout << (timer_end.tv_sec - timer_start.tv_sec) << ":" << (timer_end.tv_nsec - timer_start.tv_nsec) << std::endl;
```

The output I get is this

0:6934599

It seems that the timer only elapsed 693 milliseconds or so.

I compile the program with g++ -lrt on Linux gnu gcc 4.6. I also received a Semantic Error, says
**Symbol 'CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID' could not be resolved**

Thanks.

Comment: If you got a compiler error, how were you able to run the program?

Comment: I also find it interesting, maybe because I only get a semantic error.

Comment: If your compiler can tell you about **semantic** errors then it's smarter than any compiler I've ever seen.

Comment: I am using Linux gcc 4.6 with Eclipse CDT.

Comment: @2607: if a symbol cannot be resolved, the program won't link, and _you can't run a program that's not been linked_. So your getting a value out of something that can't exist is very confusing. Please clarify with _how_ you got that output, and what the _exact_ compiler message you're having is.

Comment: The semantic error is just an output of Eclipse CDT, not from the compiler. Check the Preferences (search for Code Analysis). This is often "not quite correct".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside the impossibility of running a program that fails to compile, sleeping is typically a system call: a kernel function is called, the kernel sends the thread to sleep, schedules other threads and processes to run (or the CPU to enter a power saving mode) and wakes the original thread up again at the requested time. During this time, the sleeping thread will not consume CPU time. The (real) time that elapses is typically referred to as *wall time*.

Contrast this to a *live wait* of a `while` loop in your code that repeatedly checks the clock and only terminates after 5 seconds have elapsed. This kind of wait *will* rack up CPU time it takes away from other processes.

Note also that 6934599 nanoseconds are about 6.93 milliseconds, not 693.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't know that if sending a thread to sleep doesn't consume CPU time, therefore the measurement won't be accurate anyway.